# How should you format data being sent between a client and server?

Tags: client-server

When dealing with a client/server based information system and you need to send information from the server to the client (in order to populate the client application) is there an efficient way of doing so?

To give you an example of the data being sent, it might be all records of staff (around 100 records) which includes; personal details, training information, meeting details etc...

This information is not required all at once, but instead when the correlating "tab" is opened within the client application...

The system will have no more than 15 clients at any one time, should I worry about sending this data efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today JSON is standard for this kind of task.
Most (client) languages provide direct usage of this format for populating results.